# How do I setup Getter and Setter methods using Array storing price at specific indexes

Tags: java, arrays, getter-setter

Currently I'm working on a project that uses an object to store some typical information for a restaurant receipt but I'm confused on how I can use an array to store information about what seat a person sat in and how much they spent.  I would like some help with the getter and setter method if you would please.

Currently in my object I have an instance variable for an array setup with 4 seats and all the values are set 0 as shown here `private double[] seatCost = {0,0,0,0};`

The getter method should be called with a seat number 1-4 (indexes 0-3) using the parameter of (index) as showed here `rc.getSeatCost(1);` and gives back the price/"bill" of that seat.

The setter method should take in the index and what the price should be set to and set it at that index (index, price at that index) as shown here `rc.setSeatCost(1, 18.64);`

I'm by no means asking someone to do this for me.  I am just asking if someone/some people could push me in the right direction by giving me ideas or thought provoking questions.  I want to learn this and do it right!

Thanks very much for reading over this and or contributing!!!

Comment: try having a Client class having seat Index as field, so to get the index we can assume that a -1 bill is an empty seat so you can loop in your array and once you got a -1 value that index is an empty seat, you will set your seat index value to zero to say that is no more free and once the order is done you will use that person object to update the seat fee because you have already as a field. wish that will help because I m not that good in english

Answer (score 0):

Getters and Setters should be included in the class that you're writing. (It might be helpful for you to copy and paste it if it isn't long.) You seem to have the right idea for what you need to do. I'll break it down a little though:

For Getters:

Getters are easy to write because you only need to enter the information you're retrieving. And example for a class called Fraction that has an int numerator and int denominator could be:

```
public int getNumerator(){
    return numerator;
}
```

If you have a class with some list, like ShoppingList that has an array of strings to store your list, your getter could look like:

```
public string getItem(int index){
    return shoppingArray[index];
}
```

For Setters:

Setters work in pretty much the same way. For the above Fraction class example, your setter for the numerator could be:

```
public void setNumerator(int numerator){
    this.numerator = numerator;
}
```

(In this case, "this" references the numerator that is found in the class, so the names are allowed to be the same in the parameter)

An example for the ShopingList could be:

```
public void setItem(int index, string item){
    shoppingArray[index] = item;
}
```